# What parameters are ok to pass to 7-zip .exe file creation while using the GUI

Tags: windows, 7-zip

What parameters are ok to pass to  the create archive wizard , in the 7-zip GUI, when you are creating a self extracting archive?   The 7-Zip GUI has a field that allows you to type in multiple parameters.

[image: screenshot]

I tried an obvious parameter (shown below) but it fails for an unknown reason:

```
-oC:\
```

Comment: *> What parameters are ok to pass to 7-zip .exe file creation while using the GUI* Whatever parameters you need (if any). Check `7-zip.chm` under *Command Line Version->Switches* for details.

Comment: Wait, are you asking what parameters to use in the GUI or what specifically parameters are required to create a self-extracting archive with the command-line version?

Comment: I am asking about the "parameter format" of the GUI. I have no problems with command line parameters. If anyone can explain why "-oC:\" will not work, that would be just as good of an answer to me.

Comment: There is no format, you just add your parameters like you would at the command-line. Is it specifically `-o` that you are trying to use? I believe that it won’t work because the output directory is derived from the `Archive` field, not the `Parameters` field. In fact, the GUI already exposes most of the parameters you are likely to use, so very few are used from the `Parameters` field.

Comment: @Synetech - ok, then can you give a working example of why (and how) someone would use that field in the GUI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can gather from your comments, it sounds like you are asking something else. It sounds like you are asking

> 1. What is the purpose of the *Parameters* field of the 7-zip dialog?
> 2. Why does it not work when you use the `-o` argument in that field?

If so, then the answers are simple (and related):

1. The *Parameters* field is for specifying any options you need that are not available via dedicated dialog controls.
2. The `-o` argument is ignored in the *Parameters* field because there is already a dedicated dialog control for the destination. The controls override corresponding options in the *Parameters* field.

Think about it this way, if you want to specify arguments in the *Parameters* field that already have dialog controls, then why use the GUI at all, why not just use the command-line in the first place? The dialog controls provide most options that are used and also reduce the possibility of error by specifying valid options. For example, the word-size options are already listed in the drop-down, so you cannot choose an invalid size like you can when specifying it in the *Parameters* field or command-line.

---

Some examples of usage of the *Parameters* field include:

- One such argument is exclusion (`-x` switch). If you want to specify filenames to be excluded, there is no option to do so in the dialog, and so you would have to enter them in the *Parameters* field.
- You would also use it to specify the `-y` switch to automatically say yes to everything instead of prompting you.
- You can even use it to *override* some of the options that the dialog automatically sets such as subdirectory recursion. When you use the dialog, it automatically sets recursion. If you don’t want that, you would need to specify `-r-` in the *Parameters* field.

For a full list, you can look at the list of command-line arguments (`7z /?`) and compare it to the controls in the dialog.

Comment: @hit-and-run-downvoter, what’s your problem‽ No, literally; what is your issue with the answer? You clicked down, so obviously you have a problem with it, but without leaving a comment to explain what your problem is, nobody can address your problem. Of course if you clicked down without having a problem, then I guess that’s a completely different kind of problem you have…

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted, its the most useful answer here

Comment: @CountMurphy, thanks for the support, unfortunately anonymous voting means no accountability and thus down-voting out of spite. `:-/`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the only parameters accepted at this time for the GUI "Add to Archive" dialog appear to be only for specifying compression method.  There appears to be confusion about this and hopefully the developers will add more parameters to this GUI in future versions.

This is what documentation states is supported parameters:

> Parameters
>   Allows you to specify parameters for compression. See the
>   -m (Method) switch description for more details. Omit the -m prefix (as in -m switch) when using this dialog box.
>
> Examples
>
> ```
>   0=PPMd uses PPMd method for compressing files.
>
>   0=bcj2 1=lzma:d23 2=lzma 3=lzma b0:1 b0s1:2 b0s2:3 uses BCJ2 filter (for x86 executables) and LZMA.
> ```

As for SFX creation it appears that there is no optional parameters to supply for the GUI.

Alternatively, The supplied documentation for command line -sfx may be of some use to you.  Also, see http://7zsfx.info/en/ for examples and more than what documentation holds for sfx creation.

Comment: I am tempted to give you the credit for the answer.  Still thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

7-Zip doesn’t use the `-o` switch for the output file path of self-extracting archives, it uses the `-sfx` switch.

For a regular archive you use:

```
-o c:\foobar.7z
```

But for a self-extracting archive you use:

```
-sfx c:\foobar.exe
```

Comment: See the screenshot I added.

Comment: The screenshot doesn’t help; I already know about the parameter text box.

Comment: Alrighty then. :)

Answer (score 0):

All GUI and Command Line parameters are in each 7-zip installed dir's `7-zip.chm` file.

page: https://sourceforge.net/p/openbor/tools/3021/tree/tools/7-Zip/7-zip.chm

download: https://sourceforge.net/p/openbor/tools/3021/tree/tools/7-Zip/7-zip.chm?format=raw

e.g. Using 7-zip GUI to compress files to a zip file. If you want to set the file name and subdir path encoding to UTF-8, you can fill param `cu` to do it. The `cu` param is locate in `7-zip.chm` --> `Command Line Version` --> `Switches` --> `-m` --> `cu=[off | on] off 7-Zip uses UTF-8 for file names that contain non-ASCII symbols.`

Answer (score 0):

**2019 update**

In answer to the bounty : Nothing has changed.

From the help of the 7-Zip File Manager, quoted:

> **Parameters**
>
> Allows you to specify parameters for compression. See the
>   [-m (Method)](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm)
>   switch description for more details. Omit the
>   -m prefix (as in -m
>   switch) when using this dialog box.
>
> **Examples**
>
> f=delta:4
>
> uses Delta:4 filter (if you want to compress WAV files).
>
> f=bcj2
>
> uses BCJ2 filter (for x86 executables).

There are minor syntactical changes from the
[answer by Sn3akyP3t3](https://superuser.com/a/414016/8672),
but in essence nothing has changed.